# WPF Check if Popup element will be automatically repositioned

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup

I'm developing a WPF control that contains a popup.

The popup is placed relatively to an element that is draggable. This element can be positioned around the edges of the screen. So every time I open the popup I need to determine whether it will fit on the screen or it will be automatically repositioned.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to centre a pop-up for example in the middle of your screen. 
Based on what you typed and on your tags I assume you need XAML to center a popupscreen.

you can do it like this: `<Popup x:Name="ParentPopup" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=MainPanel}" Placement="Center" />`